# Extending C++ functions to Python using Boost Python

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I am trying to wrap up two c++ files to be used in Python. I am using the boost python library. The files appear to compile correctly, but importing the modules results in a "ImportError: undefined symbol" error.

This issue has something to do with boost not correctly finding my dependent c++ files, but I am not clear as to how to add them.

Python Version: 2.7.12
Boost Version: 1.58
OS: Ubuntu 16.04

My code structure is as follows:

**hellomodule.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;

void say_hello(const char* name) {
    cout << "Hello " <<  name << "!\n";
    run_test();
}

#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    def("say_hello", say_hello);
}
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"
using namespace std;

void run_test(void){
    cout << "Sup";
}
```

**setup.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

module1 = Extension("hello",
                    sources = ["hellomodule.cpp", "test.cpp"],
                    libraries = ["boost_python"],
                    extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11'])

setup(name="PackageName",
    ext_modules=[module1])
```

From the command line I run "python setup.py build" which creates my hello.so file. When I try to import "hello" I get "ImportError: ./hello.so: undefined symbol: _Z8run_testv"

If someone could please point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post what version of Python and Boost you're using? Also what platform you're using. I was able to get it to work using Python 3.6.2 and Boost 1.58 on CentOS7. I had to guess the contents of test.h, but it doesn't seem like that should have much of a material impact.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.12, Boost 1.58, and Ubuntu 16.04. The contents of test.h are trivial. See below: #include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
void run_test(void);

Comment: @Seabass could you share how you got this to work? I am at a loss right now.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please provide a [mcve], including the missing header and the full transcript of the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you may have some stale files around. I was able to reproduce the issue by omitting `test.cpp` from `sources` in `setup.py`. In this case it builds just fine, but as you observed, does not import. It might be that Python is finding a version of `hello.so` that you built previously before adding `test.cpp` in.

I'd suggest removing the `build` dir and any copies of `hello.so` that might be lying around and trying to run the build from scratch again.